# Projection of a vector on a span

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection

I have the vectors:
u=$(-2,-2,-2)$, v=$(3,-1,2)$
I have to find a vector - w=$(x,y,z)$ ( I think ) on v and u.
projection of w on v is $-6v$
projection of w on u is $6u$.
I got to that point:
$-6|v|^2=wv$
$6|u|^2=wu$

but from here I am stuck.. I Dunno how to continue... saw some similar posts, but did not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{Proj}_v w = \dfrac{ w \cdot v }{ v \cdot v } v $

From this it follows that

$ - 6 = \dfrac{ w \cdot v }{ v \cdot v } $

Using the given $v = (3, -1, 2) $ we get

$ -84 = w \cdot v  $

Similarly

$ 6 = \dfrac{ w \cdot u }{u \cdot u } $

From which,

$ 72 = w \cdot u $

Now $ w $ can be expresses as the following linear combination

$ w = \alpha u + \beta v + \gamma (u \times v) $

Taking the dot products with $u$ and $v $

$ 72 = \alpha (u\cdot u) + \beta (v\cdot u) $

$ -84 = \alpha (u\cdot v) + \beta (v \cdot v ) $

Substituting $u$ and $v$

$ 72 = 12 \alpha - 8 \beta $

$ -84 = -8 \alpha + 14 \beta $

Can you take it from here ?

**EDIT:**

The last two equations, simplify to

$ 18 = 3 \alpha - 2 \beta $

$ -42 = -4 \alpha + 7 \beta $

From these $2$ equations we get

$ \alpha = \dfrac{ 18(7) - 84 }{21 - 8} = \dfrac{42}{13} $

$\beta = \dfrac{ 3(-42) + 4 (18) }{21 - 8} =- \dfrac{54}{13} $

Now $ \gamma$ is a free parameters, any real value for $\gamma$ is accepted.  And

$ u \times v = \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} && \mathbf{j} && \mathbf{k} \\-2 && -2 && - 2 \\ 3 && -1 && 2 \end{vmatrix} = (-6 , -2, 8)$

Hence,

$ w = \dfrac{42}{13} (-2, -2, -2) - \dfrac{54}{13} (3, -1, 2) +\gamma (-6, -2, 8) $

And simplifies to

$ w = \dfrac{1}{13} ( -246, - 30 , -192 ) + \gamma (-6, -2, 8) $

**Verification:**

$\text{Proj}_u w = \bigg( \dfrac{1}{13} \cdot \dfrac{ -2( -246 - 30 -192) }{12} \bigg) u = 6 u $

$\text{Proj}_v w = \bigg( \dfrac{1}{13} \cdot \dfrac{ 3(-246) - (-30) + 2(-192) } { 14 } \bigg) v = -6 v $

So the result is correct.

Comment: Hi, huge thanks for the explanation. I did the same as you till the linear combination, there I got stuck. didnt understand how to continue from there.. why did you do linear combination there? and how did you reach $a(uu)$ and beta$(vu)$? I didnt understand the movement from the linear combination to there.

Regarding the take: I will try and update :)

Comment: and if you mind explanining, what is substituting u and v? I never saw such a thing.

Also, I tried calculating the alpha and beta, i get some really ugly numbers... alpha=$\frac {42} {13}$ and beta = $\frac {-54} {13}$, is it wrong?

Comment: and lastly, if I find alpha and beta, I still need to get gama, no? the problem is, we didnt learn vector multiplication with cross on linear algebra, isn't there any other way to find gama?

Comment: Substitute $u$ and $v$ means plug in their values in the expression.

Comment: $\gamma$ is a free parameter.  So there are infinite vectors satisfying the given conditions, each with a different $\gamma$

Comment: Please check my updated solution, and check with your results.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check in a minute!!

Comment: It is juts weird to me that we needed to use cross multiplication, since we have not learned it on linear algebra, only at physics.
Also, the answer, I dont know if it is really correct, since the answer is:
https://ibb.co/Qft7H4T
I cant write it myself, since the answer itself is weird... I dont know what is the modulu there.

Comment: Are you sure about the values you gave for vectors $u $ and $v$ , is there a typo somewhere ?

Comment: Also, since you didn't learn cross multiplication, then may it is required that $w$ be in the plane containing $u $ and $v$.  If this is the case, then $ \gamma = 0 $

Comment: About the values yea, that is why its weird to me... I dont know if it is correct, the rest of the questions are the same.. ugly numbers ( although they were true ). no typo sadly.. thatss why I am confused. about crosss multiplication, yea, I thought so too, gama will just be equal to 0.

Comment: @Robin'sPremiumCoffee Hi again, please I need help with https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4454113/585488