# How to project a point into a new basis?

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

Say In $\mathbb{R}^3$ I have a point $P_{B_0} = (x, y, z)$ and its basis $B_0 = (\vec{e_0}, \vec{e_1}, \vec{e_2})$, I would like to **project** this point into a new basis $B_1 =  (\vec{f_0}, \vec{f_1}, \vec{f_2})$ as point $P_{B_1} = (x’, y’, z’)$. Please what’s the general formula to get this over with in $\mathbb{R}^n$

> I mean a formula that is function of $P_{B_0},B_0, B_1$ in relation to $P_{B_1}$ i.e. something along the lines of $P_{B_1} = \frac{B_1 P_{B_0}}{B_0} $ from $\frac{P_{B_0}}{B_0} = \frac{P_{B_1}}{B_1}$

Comment: Have you tried https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis?

Comment: @Patricio wasn’t able to get it to work

Comment: Can you be more specific about what problems you're having using the usual change of basis formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ P = B_0 P_{B_0} = B_1 P_{B_1} $

Hence,

$ P_{B_1} = (B_1)^{-1} B_0 P_{B_0} $

Comment: much love dude:)… just tried it as matrices (apologies if you ain’t no dude) it’s working